# Slow Initial RDP Connection to Windows 10

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-10

Since upgrading a machine from Windows 8.1 Professional to Windows 10 Professional (workgroup, no domain membership), I've been experiencing a rather strange issue that I can't figure out. The initial remote desktop connection is very slow to connect (on the order of two minutes). However, after the initial connection is made, I can close the connection and reconnect almost immediately. Also, after the initial connection is made, I can close the connection and reconnect using another machine entirely without experiencing the long delay. I've tested the remote desktop clients on Windows 7, 8.1, and 10, and all experience the same slow initial connection to the Windows 10 machine, so I believe the problem lies on the server side.

Things I've tried so far:

- Turning off "Automatic Root Certificates Update" via local computer policy:
  `(Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Internet Communication Settings -> Turn Off Automatic Root Certificates Update)`.
  Suggestion from [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b8e58d83-3178-4490-b4f4-1c6e5542c39a/rdp-slow-initial-connection), by user "dsoic" midway down the page. It was also suggested to disable CredSSP, but I don't think disabling Network Level Authentication is a good choice.
- Forcing TCP as the only RDP transport protocol
  `(Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Connections -> Select RDP transport protocols)`,
  suggested by user "Jayson Allen" on [spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/337988-solved-excruciating-slow-rdp-into-server-2012-hyper-v-and-its-vms?page=3). I also checked the FIPS setting, but on Windows 10 it appears to be disabled by default.

Neither has improved the situation. Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

**EDIT:** The Threshold 2 update has corrected this issue on my system.

Comment: Try and disable "Smart Card Device Enumeration Service" and see if it improves. I had a similar issue and this resolved it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried disabling the "Smart Card Device Enumeration Service", and the first login after reboot was fine. However, reconnecting to a session that has been disconnected for a while still causes a long delay. I'm not sure what would be different about reconnecting to a disconnected session vs. initial logon that would be a source of delay.

Comment: I'm having the same issue across the board with Windows 10 in an out of domain environment and I haven't figured it out.  What a pain.  Seriously microsoft, you didn't test this?

Comment: As a test, I disabled the option of requiring Network Level Authentication, but the same issue occurred. Still not sure what the root cause of this problem is.

Comment: From @eejai42: I have verified that it happens when connecting from the beta Microsoft Mac RDP client, the native Mac RDP client, the windows 8.1 & 10 MSTSC clients. The range of clients seems to indicate that the problem is on the server side, imho. If I try to connect during the initial delay (from another client) I get a message that the MSTSC service is currently busy, and it asks me to try again in a few minutes. Then, as with OP - subsequent connections are all accepted normally.

Comment: This may help you:  http://serverfault.com/questions/731722/initial-rdp-connection-to-windows-10-slow-to-connect/731723#731723

Comment: I have not earned enough rep to properly answer yet, but check if **how you address your remote machine** changes something. For me, using the "Full device name" listed in <Win> + <X> > _System_ on the remote machine (e.g. `DEVICE.domain.company.com`) resulted in very long initial connection times, while using only the shorter "Device name" (e.g. `DEVICE`) or its IP directly made the connection work _immediately_. - Grain of salt: I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop for macOS to connect to my machine so your mileage might vary. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It's a result of aggressive auto-tuning of the connection which causes the delay on startup.  Running the following should resolve your issue.

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=highlyrestricted
```

More details: [Remote Desktop slow problem solved](http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/microsoft/remote-desktop-slow-problem-solved.asp)

Comment: Alas, this doesn't seem to work. I've tried this setting on both my Windows 8.1 client and the Windows 10 session host. Once I've endured the delay and connected to Windows 10, reconnection is much quicker with or without this setting. However when I shut down the client host (as I do daily) and reconnect some time later (usually overnight), the problem reappears.

Comment: This did not work for me either (Windows 10 Professional).

Answer (score 1):

Well, after being unable to determine the root cause of the issue, I tried a fresh install of Windows 10 Professional. The reinstall has corrected the slow initial connection issue, so all that I can say is that this problem was most likely some sort of corruption or setting issue caused by the upgrade process.

Edit: I spoke too soon. The issue started again approximately one week after reinstalling Windows. I'm still searching for the root cause.

Comment: Have you been able to speak to Microsoft yet in anyway about the issue or posted to their forums?

Comment: I have not spoken to Microsoft about this issue. Which forum would you recommend?

Comment: I think they are http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by changing the Mircosoft account to local account .

Edit:
RDP initial connection is sometimes still slow , but better than using remote Microsoft account .

Comment: I'm only using a local account, so this does not work in my case.