# Initial RDP Connection to Windows 10 slow to connect

Tags: rdp, windows-10

When connecting to Windows 10 via RDP, the connection seems to hang for a while before actually connecting.  Before migrating to Windows 10, this was not an issue.  What is the recommended way to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

After doing some digging, I was able to find the solution.  It's a result of aggressive auto-tuning of the connection which causes the delay on startup.

Running the following should resolve your issue.

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=highlyrestricted
```

More details: [Remote Desktop slow problem solved](http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/microsoft/remote-desktop-slow-problem-solved.asp)